# "Don´t play on the grass boys. She said" in a reported speech mode - possible?

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to say:

> "Don't play on the grass boys," she said.

In a reported speech mode?

Comment: It's quite possible to ***say*** those words. But in ***writing***, you can't "nest" double quote marks. So if that's what you're asking about, there's your answer. Otherwise, perhaps you could edit to put the text you're asking about on a line on its own, and remove the "outer" quote marks. Then we'll know what exactly you're asking.

Comment: Normally we'd report the command as "She said not to play on the grass".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. And in fact it's quite common in literature. 
It's a [direct reported speech](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech/reported-speech-indirect-speech)": (English Grammar Today - Cambridge dictionary)

> ‘I’ve been working,’ **she said**. ✅
>
> ‘What happened to make her so angry?’ **he asked**.✅
>
> **He said**, ‘Jane will be late.’✅

All of above are correct and they were taken from the source that was mentioned above. For further reading about different types of speech, read [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech/reported-speech-indirect-speech).